# Display nodes even if it untranslated

Tags: views, 8

I've using default translate module. I enabled 2 languages, setted translation in nodetype. So now if i will setup view like this:

[image]

It will display only translated nodes. If I set all languages, it will show all nodes, but with duplicates (first and second languages).

How to set in this way: display translated nodes, but if some are not translated, display untranslated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is the combination of two things:

1. Instead of translation language, use the filter "Default translation", so that you only get the original/default/source translation for each node.
2. Then, in Language below Pager, for "Rendering Language", select "Interface text language selected for page". That will select the best available translation for the current language, just like accessing node/1.